# Why am I getting undefined reference to Class::Class()?

Tags: c++, undefined-reference

error: undefined reference to `Transaction::Transaction(QString, QDate, int, double)'

Extract from header file:

```
#include <Transaction.h>

class Product
{
public:
    virtual ~Product();
    void sell(int n);
    void restock(int n);
    void setProductCode(QString c);

    QString getSupplierCode() const;
    QString getProductCode() const;
    QList<Transaction> getTransactions();

    QString toString();
    void removeAll();
    bool isExpired() const;

protected:
    Product(QString name, int num, double seprice, double suprice, QString sc);
    Product(QStringList& prodlist);

private:
    QString m_Name;
    int m_NoOfItems;
    QString m_ProductCode;
    double m_SellingPrice;
    double m_SupplierPrice;
    QString m_SupplierCode;
    QList<Transaction> m_Transaction;
};
```

Implementation file:

```
//Sell a product
void Product::sell(int n)
{
    if(m_NoOfItems == 0)
  {
    qDebug() << "Out of stock";
  }
  else if(n < m_NoOfItems)
    {
        m_NoOfItems = m_NoOfItems -n;
        m_Transaction.append(Transaction("Sale", QDate::currentDate(),n, m_SellingPrice));
    }
    else qDebug() << "Not enough items in stock";
}

//Restock a product
void Product::restock(int n)
{
    m_NoOfItems = m_NoOfItems +n;
    m_Transaction.append(Transaction("Purchase", QDate::currentDate(),n, `m_SupplierPrice));`
}
```

---

Transaction.h

```
#ifndef TRANSACTION_H
#define TRANSACTION_H

#include <QString>
#include <QDate>

//begining of Transaction Class
class Transaction
{
public:
  Transaction(QString type, QDate date, int num, double price );
  QString toString() const;

private:
  QString m_Type;
  QDate m_Date;
  int m_NoOfItems;
  double m_PricePerItem;

};
//end of Transaction class
#endif // TRANSACTION_H
```

I am getting undefined reference to `Transaction::Transaction(QString, QDate, int, double)`. Its supposed to be as above. I had put class::class as I had mentioned the class in question already.

Comment: Where is `Transaction` defined/implemented/linked?

Comment: I figured it out, Transaction class was not visible to the implementation.

Comment: I have included the missing parts

Comment: I don't see any mention of a class called `Class` in your code, so it's likely not a relevant extract.  It's much better if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) and an exact extract of (the first few lines of) the error messages.

Comment: Thanks I have edited the line so that its clear as to what I was asking on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Transaction class was not visible. I had defined it below the Product class in the same file. I had to put it in a separate header file.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, you shouldn't be putting out-of-line function bodies in headers